# Performance issue on CInlineAction::runWithParams()

Tags: yii

Based on New Relic report, about 70% of the time was spent to handle a request consumed by `CInlineAction::runWithParams`. In fact the `Controller::action()` took only less than 20% of total time.

At first I thought it might be because of using `urlManager` to rewrite the request instead of the webserver so I let the rewrite portion to be handled by the webserver and disabled the whole `urlManager` configuration in my config file.

Based on information provided by Xdebug still there is not much difference.

Just wanted to ask if it's natural for `CInlineAction::runWithParams` takes that amount of process or there is something wrong with the configuration.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Even though i can't really tell why New Relic reports so much time spent on that method i don't think there's something wrong with your configuration. Yii will create a new `CInlineAction` object for each call to an inline action (i.e. an action defined *inline* a controller as an `action...` function, hence the name). Then `runWithParams` is then called to run the currently requested action.

So it's quite natural that you see many calls to that method. The only suspicious thing inside that method is that reflection is used to actually call the controller method. But this should not have that dramatic impact on execution time. So i'd probably blame it on the way New Relic does it's measuring.

If you really want to hunt it down, you could add some `echo microtime()` before each line in that method to find out where the cycles go.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I haven't find out where exactly the problem relies. The only thing that I suspect is the New Relic's order of report. I guess `runWithParams` is one of the earlier calls within a request until it gets to my `Controller->action()` but New Relic is reporting them as two non dependent calls which is wrong based in Xdebug log files.

`runWithParams` itself based on Xdebug just takes about 0.06ms but New Relic stats actually is reporting the sum of its time and its children not just only its time as an independent call.